# Transferring RDS from EB to a new account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am trying to move my application from one AWS account to another using the online UI for EB.

This is the steps I have done so far:

1) Downloaded the latest code off the old account

2) Created a new env using the code base from the old account

3) Created a snapshot of the RDS and shared it with the new account

4) Added the RDS snapshot to create the RDS for the new account

at step 4 I get the following error .

```
Requested DBSnapshot and Engine are incompatible.
```

I am using Ruby with Puma 2.3 as my engine and it is a Rails application.

Comment: I think I have found the problem but not sure how to solve it.

The RDS snapshot was created with postgres engine 9.5.4 - however when I load the snapshot in EB it automatically sets the engine to 5.6.39 and I can't change it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up making a blank RDS with the correct version and then once that was up and running in EB - I went back in and loaded the snapshot  which seemed to work.

Seems a bit convoluted in my opinion...